# Autodesk clear cookies issue on logout

Tags: javascript, cookies, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I am signing in Autodesk in my system and I want to logout from Autodesk , In that I want to clear out these 3 cookies accounts.autodesk.com , auth.autodesk.com , autodesk.com of Autodesk which was used by Autodesk , so How do I do it using javascript ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to clear accounts.autodesk.com  , auth.autodesk.com ,autodesk.com cookies for logout  from Autodesk using javascript because write now on logout button it doesn't logging me out coz of that saved cookies in autodesk popup, so i want to clear these cookies

Answer (score 1):

There is this post that describes how to properly sign out from Autodesk account: [Log Out Forge](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/log-out-forge)